# How does this app know I've used it before?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

There is an app that has a paid service. It allows you to use a free trial 3 times for 1 hour before it detects that you have used your 3 trials and blocks you. I tried various things, but each time it knows I have used my trials:

- un- and re-installing
- clearing app data
- creating backups with titanium backup and restoring it
- creating a new user account on my phone (android M), installing the app separately

How is this app detecting it? The only way I can reset the trials is by resetting my phone, but I can't keep doing this. Is there a way I can monitor the files the app creates/reads/writes?

Comment: As you don't give a link to "that app", we cannot say for sure. But a good guess would be it uses one of your device's identifiers. Cannot be the IMEI or device serial (or a factory-reset wouldn't cure it), but the most likely is the GAID (Google Ad ID) or the Android_ID. The former can be changed without a factory-reset: Go to *Apps › Google Settings*  and check for it (I cannot check as I'm running Google-free). The latter requires a factory-reset (or root-powers plus "dangerous commands"). A perfect and easy solution: Buy the app if you like using it. Less hassle than a reset :)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which app you are using, it's hard to provide feedback. If you have given file access to the app, it could have stored the trial usage somewhere on internal storage or on an SD card (if present). The best you can do is to search through files until you might find something.

It could have also associated itself with your Google ID. Did you ever accept a dialog asking you to choose which Google account you want to use? If so, you can not use the same Google account for a trial on any phone, and would have to use a different account.

That being said, if you have used your three trials, it seems that this is a product that you want to use, and it may be worth paying for. Keep in mind that a developer/company wrote the app, and may be providing infrastructure for its use, which costs them money. Sometimes, there are no free alternatives, and you'll have to pay to use a product or service.

Answer (score 0):

It Either Checks your Device info and saves it to their server or tracks your ip..

Comment: Both has already been addressed by answers, so this doesn't add anything new. Besides, for reasons given, the IP address is extremely unlikely – and "device info" (quite generic) wouldn't explain how a factory-reset can work around it (it's still the same device, just with another GAID).

Answer (score -4):

its using your IP address... very simple... change that and you can continue with another free trial...

Comment: What is your basis for this answer? We don't even know what app it is, and IP address checking in the modern world is almost never used since it is so easy to bypass... 20 years ago, maybe, but not today.

Comment: Not even then. Your IP address can change multiple times a day. Apart from that: How do ***you*** change your IP address when on mobile data? So even if your answer were true, it misses the essential detail.